# How to logout with facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8

I'm writing one wp8 application which uses  [the facebook c# sdk](http://csharpsdk.org/).
Everything is going well but one thing won't work (and it drive me crazy) : I can not log out the user.

I tried:

```
var logoutParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                  {
                      { "next", loginUrl }
                  };
var logoutUrl = _facebookClient.GetLogoutUrl(logoutParameters);
```

also,

```
var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new {access_token = "...", next = "...." });
```

and,

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=[redirect_uri]&access_token=[access_token]
```

Regards.

Comment: Could someone tell me why down vote my question ?  if someone think this question isn't usefull could him even try to do the same or tell me why instant down vote?

Comment: Do you get any errors when trying to log out?

Comment: No, nothing. If I was logged and I relaunch the application. My web browser reloads the user information (without asking for credential). The only way to clear it it's to change the build mode (release/debug).

Comment: @Davis changing the build mode will rebuild the application and typically trigger a redeploy of the app so you'll lose any stored credentials. What response do you get to the call to `logout.php`? Does the client have a way to clear or reset credentials? what if you try and call log-in again but with invalid credentials?

Comment: @MattLacey When I call logout.php it does the same as if I used http://facebook.com. I mean, I'm logged with my previous credentials. (same with log-in url). And no, there is no way to clear my credentials (exept with one logout). I just want to be able to reenter my credentials each time.

Comment: To get it to work you must also inform the Access Token. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24200855/194717

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within WP8 you can clear the cookies with WebBrowser.ClearCockiesAsync()

Maybe this link will help: 
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application

Comment: Thanks! Seems to not matter which instance of WebBrowser it's called on either. Simply writing await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync(); worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `loginUrl` with "http://www.facebook.com":

Like this:

```
var logoutParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                  {
                      { "next", "http://www.facebook.com" }
                  };

var logoutUrl = _facebookClient.GetLogoutUrl(logoutParameters);
```

Comment: No, it wont work. I already tried this. But Andreas's answer work fine for me.

Comment: To get it to work you must also inform the Access Token. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24200855/194717