# Facebook SDK for .NET Login Button, logout code

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I've used the Login Button Control in the Facebook SDK for .NET in an app and I need to change the Status/state of the login button control from "Logout" to "Login" i.e., I need to logout the user manually through code.

How would that be possible??

Comment: They suggest to logout deleting the Token and the session.

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml I tried that but the Button Control still shows the "logout" option and the user must click that to change it to "Login"

Answer (score 3):

Use `FacebookClient.Logout` to generate the logout url.

This is just a sample.

```
private void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient();

    var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new
                                        {
                                            next =    "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
                                            access_token = _accessToken
                                        });
    var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser.Navigated += (o, args) =>
                                {
                                    if (args.Url.AbsoluteUri == "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
                                        Close();
                                };

    webBrowser.Navigate(logoutUrl.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Make sure to persist the `access token` somewhere when you login so that you can use it to the logout too.

Comment: I was doing all this, but forgot to save `access_token`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The user is not asked for his credentials because the Facebook authentication cookie is still present in the `WebBrowser` control.

So to completely logout the user from Facebook, you need to clear the `WebBrowser` cookies.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way for erasing cookies on Windows Phone 7.

On Windows Phone 8 you just need to call [ClearCookiesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj571211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)  Method

```
await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
```

Here is a tutorial that makes use of it:

[Integrate Facebook to Your Windows Phone Application](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application)

Comment: please check my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent many hours trawling to get this.  Many thanks Kulasangar

I modified your code slightly but it works:

```
var identity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var accessToken = identity.FindFirstValue("FacebookAccessToken");
var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new
                {
                    next = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
                    access_token = accessToken
                });
Response.Redirect(logoutUrl.AbsoluteUri);
```